# Background Front Ground and layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have one background layer which have hands and trousers, one front ground layer image which is my design and several different colours of T Shirt. I am using script export layers to files(fast).

My problem is, image are saving but only background(hands and trousers) with several layers of colors of T Shirt. I am unable to add frontground on different layers. Frontground is saved on top and background is on bottom.

I want Background(hands and trousers) + layers + Frontground applied on all the layers

I am using mac system

[image: Final Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot before saving]

Thanks for commenting on the post......

I tried to add more screenshot but it says i need 10 reputation...Anyways...in the final screenshot, you can see, its adding one layer. Bottom layer as Background, top layer as foreground, and other layers as colours. Now you can see its adding background bottom layer, Top layer and colors, but when i tried to export from script, it only saves background and colors, not saving foreground.

My problem is i have different designs, and i have several layers named as different colors, Body layer as background, and one layer i have to create as T Shirt Design. I need to add this layer(Design) into all the colors with background.

As you guys can easily understand, i am not so much professional , so it would be great if you guys help me out

Comment: The script you're using is working correctly based on its description. It simply doesn't do what you're after. Find a different method, different script, or write your own.

Comment: better try to save manually if script is not working, Scripts cant do all things

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like the issue is you're wanting to do something this script isn't designed to do:

> This script allows you to export your layers as individual JPGs / PNGs at a speed much faster than the built-in script from adobe.

If I understand right you have basically this setup on your Photoshop Document:

- Foreground which has some transparency or blending mode
- ***GROUP*** of different color shirts
- Background

You want the script to apply the foreground to each color of the shirt before saving. That's however not what the script is for.

---

**Potential Solution:**

You'd probably be better off using Actions and Droplets to run through each shirt color turning the visibility on/off and then saving the full image not individual layers.

Answer (score 1):

You could arrange all the combinations you need using **Layer Comps**, and then export all Layer Comps (Menu: `Window > LayerComps`) with the standard *Layer Comps to Files* Script.